# give the app unlimited time to run in android smartphones

Tags: java, android, executorservice, smartphone

i want to build an app that provide full-text search for images in android smartphones using android studio and java, so what I'm doing is take all the paths of images with this method

```
 private ArrayList<String> getAllImagesPath(){

        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int columIndexData;
        ArrayList<String> imagesPath=new ArrayList<>();

        uri= MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection ={MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};
        cursor=MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);
        columIndexData=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String imagePath = cursor.getString(columIndexData);
                File imgFile = new File(imagePath);
                if (imgFile.exists()) {
                   // Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    imagesPath.add(imagePath);
                    Log.d("ImagePath", imagePath);
                    //getTextFromImage(myBitmap);
                    //Bitmap.relase
                    // AddToDataBase(myBitmap.toString(), getTextFromImage(myBitmap));
                }
            }
            Log.d("ImagePath", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle any exceptions gracefully
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return imagesPath;

    }
```

and i extract text from each image with this method

```
 private String getTextFromImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        TextRecognizer recognizer=new TextRecognizer.Builder(MainActivity.this).build();
        if (!recognizer.isOperational()){
            Log.d("ImagePath", "Error getTextFromImage");
            return null;
        }
        else {
            Frame frame=new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
            SparseArray<TextBlock> textBlockSparseArray=recognizer.detect(frame);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
            for (int i=0; i<textBlockSparseArray.size();i++){
                TextBlock textBlock=textBlockSparseArray.valueAt(i);
                stringBuilder.append(textBlock.getValue());
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
            }
            Log.d("ImagePath", stringBuilder.toString());
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
```

and i use ExecutorService to to avoid blocking the main UI thread.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

ArrayList<String>  imagesPaths = getAllImagesPath();
                executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (String imagePath : imagesPaths) {
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
                            String text = getTextFromImage(bitmap);
                            bitmap.recycle();
                            AddToDataBase(imagePath, text);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

that will work fine when i make it run on limited images, like 200 image, if it is more the app stop and shows (PROCESS ENDED)

so how can i optimize the code to make it run without stopping and take the time it needs

Comment: please use adb, collect some logs and share the stacktrace. thanks